# Como puedo obtener el datos ingresando una url de musica?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, express, ejs

Estoy haciendo una aplicación web de música y estoy queriendo obtener los nombres de las musicas que se van reproduciendo, y he intentado usando npms como "icecast-parser" del lado del servidor con esto.
La cosa es que da el nombre pero no se actualiza en el html. Alguien me puede decir como puedo hacerlo? Les agradeceria mucho. =>

````
let name;
const radioStation = new Parser({ url: 'http://strm112.1.fm/dubstep_mobile_mp3' });
   radioStation.on('metadata', (metadata) => {
   name = metadata.get('StreamTitle')
});

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
res.render("index", { song: name }); 
});```
````

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! en ningun lado estas tocando tu html.. sera por eso?

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.